# React Native Issue with Navigation.toggleDrawer()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I hope that all is well. I am using React Native to configure a mobile app. I ran into an issue with `navigation.toggleDrawer()`. I am trying to place a hamburger, navicon, in the top right corner. I managed to get it, but my next issue occurs when the icon is pressed. When I press the icon, I originally had `ReferenceError: Property 'useNavigation' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes`, but now I get `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` after installing and importing `useNavigation` by adding `import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';` to my code. The code is below for visual reference. What exactly am I doing wrong here, or am I missing? Thank you in advance for your time.

```js
//Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { AsyncStorage, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';


//Screens
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Logout from './screens/Logout';

//Code
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const navigation = useNavigation();

const StackedScreens = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator 
      initialRouteName='Dashboard'
      screenOptions={headerStyle}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Logout" component={Logout}/>            
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['purple', 'gold']} style={styles.linearBGContainer}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <StackedScreens/>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </LinearGradient>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const headerStyle = {
  title: 'Catching Souls',
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'purple' },
  headerTintColor: 'white',
  headerTitleAlign: 'center',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  headerRight: () => 
      (
        <Icon name='menu' size={50} color='white'
          onPress={()=> navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
      ),
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  linearBGContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the useNavigation hook outside of a functional component, which is causing the "Invalid hook call" error. Hooks like useNavigation can only be used within functional components, not at the top-level scope of your module. You should move the useNavigation hook usage inside the component where you're rendering the header.

```js
const StackedScreens = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation(); // Move the hook inside the component

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator 
      initialRouteName='Dashboard'
      screenOptions={headerStyle(navigation)} // Pass navigation as an argument
    >
      {/* ... (other screen components) */}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Then set headerStyle to accept navigation

```js
const headerStyle = navigation => { // Accept navigation as an argument
  return {
    title: 'Catching Souls',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'purple' },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontSize: 25,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    headerRight: () => 
        (
          <Icon name='menu' size={50} color='white'
            onPress={()=> navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}}
          />
        ),
  };
}
```

You can also return another function that takes the screen options and modifies them. This way, the useNavigation hook will be properly used within the component, and the header configuration will be applied to the screens. Make the changes to fit your requirement.

```js
const headerStyle = navigation => {
  return options => ({ // Return a function that takes screen options
    ...options, // Keep the original options
    title: 'Catching Souls',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'purple' },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontSize: 25,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    headerRight: () => 
        (
          <Icon name='menu' size={50} color='white'
            onPress={()=> navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}}
          />
        ),
  });
}
```

Comment: I still recieve `TypeError: navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes` when pressing the button.

Comment: function might not be directly available is some versions of React Navigation. import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'; Then dispatch action from navigation. I have updated my code. Hopefully this should work.

Comment: That worked! I had to do some little tweaks to include `createDrawerNavigator();` but now it works with the explanation you provided! Thanks for your help!